# Php double time zome manipulation

Tags: php, datetime

I need to manipulate a datetime generated via mysql db either by by adding a particular +/-GMT value or first minus -08:00 from the time then +/-GMT. For example now I got this value capture 2012-05-25 03:04:28. I need to first minute -08:00 then -06:00? What is the best way to achieve this via php?

Comment: what's the TZ of the original datetime? Without that, any manipulations you do will be somewhat pointless.

Comment: @marcb the TZ of original will be either +08:00 or +00:00. So if it is +08:00 that is why I want to minus -08:00 ?

Comment: Then use http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Comment: I have tried this function $date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Beijing'));. Is it possible to replace the country name with the exact =/-GMT value is there any function for that?

Comment: I am trying like nothing appears $date = date_create('2000-01-01', timezone_open('GMT+0200'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

Answer (score 0):

you should take a loot at PHP's built in `DATETIME` class

```
//create new datetime instance
$dateTime = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
echo $dateTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

//add +1 day
$dateTime->modify("+1 day");
```

[DateTime::add()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) - Adds an amount of days, months, years, hours, minutes and seconds to a DateTime object.
[DateTime::sub()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) - Subtracts an amount of days, months, years, hours, minutes and seconds from a DateTime object.

more information can be found here http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: I went through your link I put this $oDateA = new DateTime('2012-01-01 12:00:00'); even it does not work. Any reason for this?

Comment: I am trying like nothing appears $date = date_create('2000-01-01', timezone_open('GMT+0200'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";